# Talend Data Integration - Read Multiple Files from a folder and load the data in mysql database

Tags: talend

I have 5 files in a folder.file names are stored in date format like "2015-09-10.txt" to "2015-09-15.txt".

if I give starting file name as 2015-09-11.txt and end file is 2015-09-13.txt then it will read all the files present in between these two files(i.e read 11,12 and 13 date files).and load data into database. the other files will not insert in database.

my current Talend Package is :
tFileList -> tFileInputDelimited -> tMapProcessing -> tMysqlOutput.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this file mask in the tFileList:

```
"2015-09-1[1-3]"
```

if you have something more complicated, generate the file name using tJavaFlex and iterate over file names:

```
tJavaFlex ------(iterate)------tFileInputDelimited-------(main)------tMap-------(main)--- tMysqlOutput
```

Comment: but if there are 1000 number of files in a folder and i want to load 300 files from that.in that case i have to add 300 file mask in tFileList. IS NOT A WAY TO PASS FIRST AND LAST RANGE IN FILE MASK ?

Comment: @Param FileMAsk is a [java regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), so you dont need to add 300 filemask, as you can see in my example: `"2015-09-1[1-3]"` this mask serve 3 files not only one, and as explained above if your case is complicated you can generate the file name not filemask using java code.